# Make Table of Content link to current document for headings inside tables

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents, cross-reference

I'm creating a document in which I use header styles to create a table of content. These header styles I use inside a table as you can see in the image below

Table used for referencing:

[image]

Now if I want to navigate to the heading, using the link in the table of content it links me to my personal computer, not to the current document.

Table of content:

[image]

How do I make the link reference to the current document, instead of the document on my PC?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by using the toggle field code (rightclick on ToC) and removing the hyperlink.

[ToC with updated hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FZyO.png)

After doing this you update the table, but only the page numbers. The hyperlinks now refer to the current document and can be used by other people as well.